# How to make EF not write property matching identity column when saving to DB?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, sqlite

I've got an issue with SQLite and EntityFramework.
My entity class has an Id property which maps to an identity column that is also the PK. When I insert a new entity model object to my DB via

```
_dbContext.Images.Add(imageEntity);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

then it will always insert the object with **imageEntity.Id = 0** because 0 is default for int. There is an attribute **[NotMapped]** which isn't what I need, it's for when you have an additional property in your entity class that doesn't exist in the table. Mine exists in the table, I just don't want to write it, the DB should take care of this.

I would like to make EF behind the scenes to produce a statement like this:

```
insert into Images (Views, Rating) values (100, 5.5)
```

instead of this:

```
insert into Images (Id, Views, Rating) values (0, 100, 5.5)
```

Anybody an idea how to do this?

Also the latter insert statement works (if there's no Id = 0 entry already), but why? Shouldn't an identity column always be protected from outside value insertion?

**UPDATE:**

As a workaround I've tried to let EF create a new entity model for me like this

```
var temp = _dbContext.Images.Create();
```

I thought maybe then I'll be able to replace everything except for the Id value and save it to the DB, but what I get is an object with `temp.Id = 0` again. I don't know if EF or SQLite is fooling me

Comment: What data type is your ID? SQLite only supports autoincrement primary keys that are 64 bit (it’s just a shortcut for rowid), therefore your ID must be a long and not an int. This is one area where SQLite diverges quite a lot from MSSQL and others.

Comment: See: https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Comment: I know about that catchy bit, I've looked it up, I use INTEGER as they recommended. But the issue is (I think) that EF tries to write the Id column at all. When I manually insert into the DB via SQL statement without specifying a value for Id, then the Id will get incremented as expected

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

As attribute of your property.
 This leaves responsibility of generating values on insert to db

Comment: Well this sounds like exactly what I need, but it does not work, still the same. Is this limited to use in conjunction with CodeFirst? I'm using DbFirst

Comment: Should not mattter is DbFirst or CodeFirts. Do you have the [Key] attribute also on the property?

Comment: Yes, I've tried with both attributes and with either of them. Still don't know if this is an EF problem or a SQLite problem. I'm really lost on this, I've set up the table as the SQLite website suggests:

`CREATE TABLE [Images] ([Id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, ...)`

Comment: So what happens when you insert without the use of EF? Is it generating the Id? I never used SQL lite myself..

Comment: Please see the two SQL statements in my posted question, both work, if I specify Id, then SQLite will accept it if not already taken, if I don't specify it SQLite will generate and auto increment it as desired.

Comment: So can you figure out what SQL EF generated?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183078/discussion-between-aldert-and-dandan).